# Undefined method "Get" and "Let" with Rspec 3 - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec3

I've decided to start a new project using the new Rspec 3 (+ capybara/factory_girl) and am having trouble learning the new syntax. Right now I have

user_pages_spec.rb (Feature)

```
scenario "Signing Up" do

        let(:submit) { "Sign up" }

        scenario "With valid information" do
            background do
                fill_in "Username", with: "example"
                fill_in "Email", with: "example@example.com"
                fill_in "Password", with: "foobar123"
                fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "foobar123"
            end

            scenario "should create a user" do
                expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
            end
        end
    end
```

Fails with undefined method 'let'. And:

static_pages_spec.rb (controller)

```
describe StaticPagesController do

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :home
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

with "undefined method 'get'. (This is just the default controller spec)

Answer (score 5):

When upgrading existing project from RSpec 2.x to 3.0 had same problem.

It was fixed for me with an explicit setting of the type.

Could you try this:

> describe StaticPagesController, type: :controller do

EDIT:

I found now that the more structural cause and solution is that
in RSpec 3, I needed to add:

> config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

in the config block in spec_helper.rb

Comment: Ahh thanks for this, it solved my controller issue, but I've still got no method "let" bugging me.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `undefined method let` because capybara defines `scenario` an alias of `it` and `feature` as alias of `describe`.  However, `let` is available in an example group context (a `describe` or `context` block) but not an individual example (and `it` block). So your example is equivalent to:

```
it "Signing Up" do
  let(:submit) { "Sign up" }

  it "With valid information" do
    background do
      fill_in "Username", with: "example"
      fill_in "Email", with: "example@example.com"
      fill_in "Password", with: "foobar123"
      fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "foobar123"
    end

    it "should create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

...but should be:

```
feature "Signing Up" do
  let(:submit) { "Sign up" }

  context "With valid information" do
    background do
      fill_in "Username", with: "example"
      fill_in "Email", with: "example@example.com"
      fill_in "Password", with: "foobar123"
      fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "foobar123"
    end

    scenario "should create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Or, if you want to stick with pure RSpec constructs (rather than the capybara aliases):

```
describe "Signing Up" do
  let(:submit) { "Sign up" }

  context "With valid information" do
    before do
      fill_in "Username", with: "example"
      fill_in "Email", with: "example@example.com"
      fill_in "Password", with: "foobar123"
      fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "foobar123"
    end

    it "should create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```